# Построение некластерного индекса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли отличия при построении некластерного индекса:

- на таблице с уже существующим кластерным индексом
- на таблице без кластерного индекса

?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под словами "отличия при построении"?

Answer (score 5):

В таблицах с существующим кластерным индексом во всех остальных индексах в качестве указателя на запись используется ключ кластерного индекса. Таким образом при поиске по некластерному индексу в таких таблицах сначала ищется указатель, а потом по этому ключу производится поиск в кластерном.

В таблицах без кластерного индекса все индексы в качестве указателя используют RID, который напрямую переводится в физический адрес записи на диске. Таким образом на таблицах без кластерного индекса поиск по любым индексам происходит быстрее, т.к. не надо заглядывать в кластерный

С точки зрения оператора DDL create index никакой разницы в синтаксисе нет (кроме отсутствия слова clustered)

Comment: Все хорошо, небольшое уточнение: row identifier в куче (heap) обычно сокращается как RID, а не RowID - лучше использовать общепринятое сокращение, чтобы не путать.

Comment: @minamoto Ok, принято